# Pytorch Model set GPU to run on Nvidia gpu

Tags: pytorch, gpu, nvidia

I am learning ML and trying to run the model(Pytorch) on my Nvidia GTX 1650.

```
torch.cuda.is_available() => True
model.to(device)
```

Implemented the above lines to run the model on GPU, but the task manager shows two GPU

```
1. Intel Graphics
2. Nvidia GTX 1650
```

The fluctuation in CPU usage is shown on Intel and not on Nvidia.

How I can run it on Nvidia GPU?

NOTE: The code is working fine and is getting executed on the Intel one with around 90-100s time of epoch.

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Comment: @molbdnilo Happy :). Now, can you help me by answering the question or you want to correct my English?

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
  device = torch.device("cuda:0")
```

Comment: @aayush then can you please try `torch.device("cuda:1")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it works

```
device = 'cuda'
check = torch.cuda.current_device()
print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(check)) 

#model.to(device)
```